# Error when creating a Toplevel widget in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I'm coding an application to control serial connected device, right now I'm stuck in a GUI error, here is the simplified code:

```
    import Tkinter

class PaginaPrincipale(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)

        def connetti():
            pagina_connessione=Tkinter.Toplevel()
            pagina_connessione.title("Gestione connessione")

            pagina_connessione.mainloop()


        self.parent = parent
        self.grid()
        self.gestisci_connessione = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Connetti!", command=connetti)
        self.gestisci_connessione.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    applicazione = PaginaPrincipale(None)
    applicazione.title = 'Pannello di controllo'
    applicazione.mainloop()
```

When I run the program I get this error:`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

I'm new to Python2.7, I hope someone could tell me what I did wrong!

Comment: `applicazione.title = 'Pannello di controllo'`

Answer (score 1):

The widget has a method named `title`, which you can use to set the title. However, you are replacing this function with a string when you do this:

```
applicazione.title = 'Pannello di controllo'
```

Once you've done that, any subsequent attempt to call the function `title` will result in the error you get (ie: you can't "call" a string).

Instead, you need to call `title` as a function:

```
applicazione.title('Pannello di controllo')
```

Comment: I have noted that the error arises also without `pagina_connessione.title("Gestione connessione")` and also using `pagina_connessione.title('Gestione connessione')`

Comment: @DavideDes: yes, it will arise any time you try to use `title` as a function once you convert the title attribute to a string. That's the point: you're destroying the function and replacing it with a string. Any time after that, if you try to use it as a function you will get that error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't cath it at the beginning.